# Can we checkpoints in VSTS using Visual Studio.

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

Can we insert checkpoints in the scripts. For example In load tests. we get results for each URL. If site is using same URL for many different pages, that pages lumped together into single URL in the result. In QALoad, it was possible to create "checkpoints" in the script, and that is how we were able to see the performance for each page, regardless of URL. Can we achieve this by VSTS ? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two possible mechanisms.

On each request you can set a "[reporting name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997829%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)". This can be set and updated via the properties panel of the request; but that can be tedious to use. The "[Set request details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356201%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)" panel can be opened with one of the web test icons and that allows reporting names (and also think times and response time goals) to be set for all the requests in the test. The reporting names are used in the various reports from Visual Studio. Some people recommend that reporting names be given to all requests and that they include sequence numbers that make it clear how the various requests relate to the flow through the test.

Another option is to put requests into "[transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182547%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)". However, transactions are more useful for grouping small numbers of requests that are to be reported as a group as well as individually.